# As-Clause Dependent

Tags: word-meaning, conjunctions

According to the *Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language*, the *as*-clause as a dependent of a nominal could be interpreted as follows:

1. "The plan as current conceived" means the plan was conceived in such-and-such a form.
2. "The church as it was in 1900" means the church was in such-and-such a state in 1900.

So, for this made-up phrase of mine:

> the law as it affected people

I try an interpretation similar to the first two phrases in the grammar text:

> the law was in such-and-such [***something***]

But I don't know what that [***something***] should be.  Did I make an error?

---

EDIT:

Inspiration for this question came from pages 1146 and 1150 of the CGOTEL.

Comment: Your interpretation does not parallel the CGEL constructions, where the verb in the definition is the verb in the *as* clause. Try this: The law affected people in such-and-such ways.

Comment: @StoneyB  Do you have a copy of the CGOTEL?  I added to the my question the page numbers of the CGOTEL where I found the example phrases.

Comment: @meatie I noticed that so far you have not accepted any of the answers to your questions. Does this mean we have not been able to help you even once? If you find an answer helpful, it is a good idea to mark it as one. Here is how it is done: http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Here's a real example of use: ["Edwards published an account of the legal status of women in Canada in 1908 and a review of Alberta law **as it affected** women and children in 1917"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IHZhBKRH080C&lpg=PA275&dq=%22law%20as%20it%20affected%22&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q=%22law%20as%20it%20affected%22&f=false). Is this example representative of the usage you're interested in?

Comment: @Nico Yes!  So what does it mean? "Alberta law ***as it affected*** women"?

Comment: I reckon the meaning appears as acception 2 in the [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as) under *subordinating conjunction*. It is equivalent to "a review of Alberta law **in the way that** it affected women and children".

Comment: @Nico So, the phrase "*Alberta law* **as** *it affected women*" by itself would incomplete because the "*as*" is dangling?  That "*as*" has to modify something outside the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

I think the meaning of **as** in:

> the law **as** it affected people

corresponds to acception 2 in the [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as) under *subordinating conjunction*, and thus, it could be rewritten as:

> the law **in the way that** it affected people

---

## Longer answer

To understand why this use of **as** is classified as that of a *subrodinating conjunction* is better to consider a full example:

> Edwards published an account of the legal status of women in Canada in 1908 and a review of Alberta law **as it affected** women and children in 1917.
>    <sub>[(The Prairie West as Promised Land, edited by R. Douglas Francis, Chris Kitzan)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IHZhBKRH080C&lpg=PA275&dq=%22law%20as%20it%20affected%22&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q=%22law%20as%20it%20affected%22&f=false)</sub>

The above example is a **complex sentence**, made up of a *main clause* and a *subordinated clause*.

The **main clause**:

> Edwards published an account of the legal status of women in Canada in 1908 and a review of Alberta law

is called *main*, because it could appear without the subordinated clause. The **subordinated clause**:

> as it affected women and children in 1917.

is called *subordinated* because its meaning is incomplete without the main clause.

The **subordinating conjunction** defines the relation between the main and the subordinated clause. In this case, **as** clarifies that *"the review of Alberta law"* is limited to *the effects* that this law has upon *people*.

Comment: So, the "*as*" in "*the law* **as** *it affected people*" is different from the "*as*" in, let say, "*the church* ***as** *it existed in 1900*", with the latter phrase not suffering the same incompleteness that the former phrase suffers?

Comment: @meatie I think it is the same, because you can still replace "as" with "in the way/manner/form/style/fashion that", i.e.: "the church in the way that it existed in 1900".

Comment: But "*the church* **as** *it existed in 1900*" seems to be more standalone than "*the law* **as** *it affected people*", because in the former, the "*as*" does not need to reach outside the phrase to modify something, whereas in the latter the "*as*" has to reach outside the phrase.

Comment: [Here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=td3tcLWvSNkC&lpg=PA103&dq=%22law%20as%20it%20affected%22&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=%22law%20as%20it%20affected%22&f=false) is an example where *"the christian law as it affected muslims"* stands alone.

Comment: That is just a title.  In a complete sentence, "*the law* **as** *it affected people*" doesn't seem to be able to stand alone.

Comment: Neither *"the law as it affected people"* nor *"the church as it existed in 1900"* is a complete sentence.

Comment: In "*the church as it existed in 1900*", "*as*" refers to an attribute of the church (form).  But in "*the law as it affected people*", "*as*" seems to refer to an external activity being done to the law.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16030/discussion-between-nico-and-meatie).